# Joi error validation throws error in node js

Tags: node.js, npm, joi

I am using JOI to validate request object as below
(JOI version used "joi": "^17.2.1")

```
const Joi=require('joi');
app.post('/api/saveMovieList',(req,res)=>{
  var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required()
  });
  
  constr result=Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
  console.log(result);
});
```

getting error as **Joi.validate is not a function**

If I use

```
constr result=schema.validate(req.body, schema);
console.log(result);
```

getting error  message as **Invalid message options**

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you actually tried reading the documentation? Or even the first example? It's `schema.validate( req.body)` assuming that `req.body` is already a suitable json object

Comment: I have read the document and this is my first example.
const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required()
    };
   
     console.log(schema.validate(req.body, schema));

Comment: Got  it thanks
const schema = Joi.object({
            name: Joi.string().min(6).required()
        });
            
        const validation = schema.validate(req.body);

Answer (score 0):

Following code solved my issue

```
const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().min(6).required()
    });
        
    const validation = schema.validate(req.body);
```